# What is difference between `Wireless Universal Repeater` and `Wireless Distribution System(WDS)`?

Tags: networking, wifi, d-link

I have a [DWL-2100AP](http://www.support.dlink.com/emulators/dwl2100ap/210/HomeWizard.html), which has more extra modes other than `Wireless Access Point`:

1. Wireless Acess Point
2. Wireless Client
3. Universal Repeater
4. WDS with AP
5. WDS

My question is: what is difference between `Universal Repeater` and `WDS` ?

Comment: The short version: WDS is real bridging, Universal Repeater is a form of NAT where the repeater impersonates its clients. WDS must be configured at both ends. Universal Repeater will work even if it only has a normal client/station connection to the access point it's repeating.

Comment: @David, can i use repeater without entering wep-or-wpa psk into AP? i mean Ap just repeat the packet wthout manipulating it ?

Comment: Certainly not. Repeater is a form of NAT where the repeater impersonates its clients. It must not only understand the packets but manipulate them so that the repeater appears to be the client to the access point.

Comment: Somebody please explain how answers to this question are not "supported by facts, references, or expertise".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WDS is real bridging, Universal Repeater is a form of NAT where the repeater impersonates its clients. WDS must be configured at both ends. Universal Repeater will work even if it only has a normal client/station connection to the access point it's repeating.

Answer (score 8):

Was all ready to start explaining but found a table that makes it much easier to explain.

Detail here:
http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeating_Mode_Comparisons

[image]

Comment: very useful thanks. but i do not understand i have a `repeater` or `repeater bridge` ?